# express passport-linkedin, making api requests

Tags: node.js, linkedin-api, passport.js

I'm using `express` and `passport-linkedin`. The authentication flow works fine, I can get the user's basic profile, and now I want to make an API request. `/v1/people/~/connections`, for example.

I've done some reading and trial and error, but all I get is `Wrong Authentication Scheme` or `Internal Server Error`.

I have the `token` and `tokenSecret` given to the `verify` callback of the `LinkedInStrategy` instance. How do I go from those to an authorized API request?

Comment: what's the value of req.isAuthenticated()?

Comment: `true`. Authentication works. I can read the user's name, surname, etc; but I don't know how to make an authorized request with those tokens

Comment: ok gotcha, check my answer

Answer (score 1):

I use a 'isLegit' function running as middleware.

Example :

```
app.get('/api/mysecuredpage',isLegit,function(req,res){
    res.render('mysecurepage');
});

function isLegit(req, res, next) {
    // if user is authenticated in the session, next
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    // if they aren't send an error
    res.json({error:'You must be logged in to view information'});
}
```

EDIT :

To make a request to the linkedIn api, just set up your request with the following options :

```
  var options = { 
        url: 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections',
        headers: { 'x-li-format': 'json' },
        qs: { oauth2_access_token: user.access_token }
      };
   request(options,function(err,res,body){
     console.log(body);
   });
```

`access_token` is the name of the variable in your passport strategy, it could be different depending how you've set it up. basically, it's one of the fields of your authenticated user ;-)

Comment: How do you make an API request, like `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections`?